# Using __class__ to get properties when deriving Enum

Tags: python, class, inheritance, enums

I want to extend `Enum` class and add a utility function, which would be utilized by other classes.

Consider this code:

```
from enum import Enum

class BaseEnum(Enum):
    def get_items():
        print(__class__)
        return __class__.__members__.items()

class DerivedEnum(BaseEnum):
    X = 1
    Y = 2

print(BaseEnum.get_items())
print(DerivedEnum.get_items())
```

This, obviously, does not work as intended, as `__class__` always refers to `BaseEnum`.

I know I can change the code to:

```
from enum import Enum

def get_enum_items(enum_class):
    return enum_class.__members__.items()

class AnotherEnum(Enum):
    X = 1
    Y = 2

    def get_items():
        return get_enum_items(__class__)

print(AnotherEnum.get_items())
```

This indeed does what I wanted, but requires me to write exactly the same method for all my `Enum` sub-classes I write.

Is there anything like `__actual_class__` in Python? I guess it'd be needed to make something like a virtual static method.

As far as I understand `Enum` class, we're never actually instantiating it, so I can see no way to use references to instances (such as `type(self)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work with a `classmethod`:

```
from enum import Enum

class BaseEnum(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def get_items(cls):
        print(cls)
        return cls.__members__.items()

class DerivedEnum(BaseEnum):
    X = 1
    Y = 2

print(BaseEnum.get_items())
print(DerivedEnum.get_items())
```

Comment: It does indeed! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `classmethod` is the most straight-forward way, as shown by [bruno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41634524/208880).  However, unless you need the result as a list of `(name, member)` tuples then the easiest way is:

```
>>> list(DerivedEnum)
[<DerivedEnum.X: 1>, <DerivedEnum.Y: 2>]
```

As far as instantiating Enum classes:  each member is an instance of its class, so you could do:

```
def get_items(self):
    return self.__class__.__members__.items()
```

While the `classmethod` is a better fit in this case (since you are accessing only class data), it is possible to add behavior that depends on the member, just like with normal classes/instances.